How to list disk size available and used for all nodes in a docker swarm from the manager host using nodejs?
Is it possible to retrieve information about disk size (both used and available) for all nodes in a docker swarm by running a nodejs app on the host machine using dockerode?
I have tried this using dockerode:
const nodes = await docker.listNodes()
for (const node of nodes) {
  console.log('node', node) // Does not give information about disk size under resources ..
}

const volumes = await docker.listVolumes()
for (const volume of volumes.Volumes) {
  console.log('volume', volume) // Does not give information per node ..
}

API DOCS, Chat-GPT and Gemini could also not help me resolving this.
